# How to trigger a jenkins build from slack via middleware

Tags: jenkins, middleware, slack

I am trying to trigger a Jenkins build from Slack and it looks like I might have to write new Middleware. Can anyone help with this as I am not really strong in programming and scripting?

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty detailed blog post [here](https://sonnguyen.ws/how-to-trigger-a-jenkins-build-from-slack/) by Nguyen Sy Thanh Son that delineates how to do this in detail. At a high level, it basically comes down to configuring your Jenkins job so that it can be triggered remotely and creating a new Slack command that triggers the Jenkins job.